# Android: Vibrator doesn't work. Foce Close emulator

Tags: android, crash, vibration

hey Guys, I'm still an Android & Java noob, but everything I've seen is telling me this should totally work, but it doesn't!  not in the emulator, not on the phone..  I'm trying to use the vibrator using vibrate(500);  ..I get an " application stopped unexpectedly " error

what am I missing?

code below:

```
package com.phys;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class phys extends Activity {

 Vibrator vibr;
 Button but;
 TextView txt;
 int counter = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        vibr = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        but = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        but.setOnClickListener(clk);
    }

    OnClickListener clk = new OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   txt.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
   //do something else
   vibr.vibrate(500);
   counter++;
  }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to look at LogCat and examine the stack trace associated with your " application stopped unexpectedly " error. That will give you more information about where you are going wrong.

I suspect the problem is that you are missing the `VIBRATE` permission. If so, add this as a child of your `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Yup, you were right.  I didn't have the permission in the manifest.

Thanks!