# What is wrong with my vibrate?

Tags: android

Since i added the vibrator my app crashes?

Code:

```
package com.flag.fun;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class lvl01Activity extends Activity   {
EditText input;
SharedPreferences someData;
public int n;
public static String fileName = "myfile";
int p = 0;
int i = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lvl01);

    final Vibrator  k = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    someData = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);

    final MediaPlayer soundRight = MediaPlayer.create(lvl01Activity.this, R.raw.right);
    final MediaPlayer soundWrong = MediaPlayer.create(lvl01Activity.this, R.raw.wrong);
    final TextView lvl01tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lvl01answer);
    final ImageView lvl01iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lvl01display);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lvl01input);
    Button lvl01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lvl01check);
     lvl01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String answer = input.getText().toString();
                   if(answer.contentEquals("canada") || answer.contentEquals("Canada")){
                    if(p == 0){
                    lvl01tv.setText("correct");
                    soundRight.start();
                    lvl01iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                    k.vibrate(500);
                    p = 5;
                    i = 5;
                        n = 2;
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
                        editor.putInt("key", n);
                        editor.commit();
                        }
                }else {
                    if(p == 0){
                        soundWrong.start();
                        k.vibrate(1000);
                        lvl01iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
                        lvl01iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                        lvl01tv.setText("wrong");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Button lvl01next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lvl01next);
        lvl01next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(i == 5){
                Intent lvl01Intent = new Intent("com.fun.flag.LVL01CHECK");
                startActivity(lvl01Intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "first finish this level", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    k.vibrate(1000);
                }
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: have you added permission in manifest? can you paste the logcat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Vibrator doesn't work. Foce Close emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604574/android-vibrator-doesnt-work-foce-close-emulator)

Comment: Lol, forgot to add the permission, thanks for reminding me